# Make Wordpress navigation links with hashtag

Tags: jquery, wordpress, plugins, navigation

I'm fairly new to the Wordpress world, and i'm already in doubt about something.

I've made a HTML template with some hashtag menu action going on (i'm using this plugin: http://www.asual.com/jquery/address/). Which means that the page **do not** reload when a user is navigating the page. Wordpress' nature does not work that way. If i create a page in Wordpress, i get a link like this: http://website.com/sample-page/ but i want it like this instead: http://website.com/wordpress/#/sample-page/.

How can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Menu setting to customize the menu, putting in static URLs and thus add # where ever you want in the URL.

Comment: Is there a more permanent way? It seems kind of stupid to do this every time i need to add a page

Answer (score 0):

Mikkel, you could also try adding this to your .htaccess file:

```
RewriteRule ^/(.*) /wordpress/#/1$ [R=301,L,NE]
```

This should grab the path after the .com/ and throw "/wordpress/#/" in front of it.

Comment: I'm actually using this on localhost, will this only work on a "real" website?

Comment: The RewriteRule will work on a live server as long as mod_rewrite is running. If your server supports WordPress I'm sure it will run RewriteRule. Yes, it should work.